# Send Enter key press to active windows in winAPI

Tags: windows, winapi

I have opened a process using CreateProcess like this:

```
CreateProcess(NULL,"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\PPTVIEW.EXE C:\\Users\\DRILON\\Desktop\\a.pps",NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&sai,&pi);
```

As you can see this process opens a pps file. Now I want to send and enter key press to the presentation (which will change the slides). I have tried a lot of codes but none is working.
I have tried:

```
HWND powerpoint = GetActiveWindow();
PostMessage(powerpoint, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

Also

```
SendMessage(powerpoint, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan('c'), 1);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I solved the problem. Whoever faces with the same issue then here is the answer.

keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, 0, 0);

This sends a keydown command to the active widnwos.

Comment: A key press isn't a single message.  It's two messages and you're not sending the most important one, the WM_KEYUP message.

Comment: Typically, SendInput() is preferred over keybd_event().

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's some COM API that would be nicer than just sending key presses.

Comment: @CareyGregory I tried your suggestion but it is still not working.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have also tried SendInput() before asking the question here but mos probably I did something wrong and it didnt work. As th last and the only solution I tried keybd_event().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerPoint's object model, using the equivalent in your language of:

```
CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application").ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
```